# How to handle taps on a custom callout view?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, swift, mapkit

I am adding a callout view like this:

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!,
        didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {
    let calloutView = UIView(frame:
        CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 120))

    calloutView.backgroundColor = UIColor.purpleColor()
    calloutView.center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetWidth(view.bounds) / 2.0, 0.0)
    calloutView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 1.0)
    calloutView.layer.masksToBounds = false

    calloutView.userInteractionEnabled = true
    let calloutViewTapRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self,
        action: "onCalloutViewTap")
    calloutView.addGestureRecognizer(calloutViewTapRecognizer)

    view.addSubview(calloutView)
}
```

Though my `onCalloutViewTap` function is never called... I am curious to understand why and to get something that works to handle interactions with my callout view.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's because your annotation view only detects touches inside its bounds. Since your callout view extends beyond the bounds, the subview doesn't recognize the tap. You need to override the `pointInside:withEvent:` method in the annotation view so your callout will actually detect the touch.

Here's an example in Objective-C:

```
- (BOOL)pointInside:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent*)event
{
    CGRect rect = self.bounds;
    BOOL isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point);

    if (!isInside)
    {
        for (UIView *view in self.subviews)
        {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, point);

            if (isInside)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return isInside;
}
```

**EDIT**:

Swift version:

```
override func pointInside(point: CGPoint, withEvent event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let rect = self.bounds
    var isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(rect, point)

    if (!isInside) {
        for subview in subviews {
            isInside = CGRectContainsPoint(subview.frame, point)

            if (isInside) {
                break
            }
        }
    }

    println(isInside)

    return isInside;
}
```

Comment: Thanks :D I'm adding the swift version to your answer.

Comment: Thanks. For other people, note that in swift you can easily override this method by extending MKAnnotationView.

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4.0

```
override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
    let rect = self.bounds;
    var isInside: Bool = rect.contains(point);
    if(!isInside)
    {
        for view in self.subviews
        {
            isInside = view.frame.contains(point);
            if isInside
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return isInside;
}
 override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
    let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
    if (hitView != nil)
    {
        self.superview?.bringSubview(toFront: self)
    }
    return hitView
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing from annotation view swift 5

```
override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event)
        if (hitView != nil)
        {
            self.superview?.bringSubviewToFront(self)
        }
        return hitView
    }
    override func point(inside point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> Bool {
        let rect = self.bounds;
        var isInside: Bool = rect.contains(point);
        if(!isInside)
        {
            for view in self.subviews
            {
                isInside = view.frame.contains(point);
                if isInside
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return isInside;
    }
```