# Map Custom View Annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotation, mkannotationview

I am trying to create a custom annotation, which have two button. i have also implement the custom annotation view with two button. But , my question is that. When i am click on the button, my button action are not call. So please help me. How it is possible. And  I am using this following code to create 'XIB' and call into the required method.

First you look it this image url.

1: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOT7m.png

This code use to create a custom view.

```
import UIKit

class YSCustomCallOutView: UIView {

@IBOutlet var ysSeeDirections_Button: UIButton!
@IBOutlet var ysSeeListingDetail_Button: UIButton!
var view:UIView!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    setUp()
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {

    super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    setUp()
}

func setUp(){

    view = loadViewFromNib()
    view.frame = bounds
    view.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleHeight
    addSubview(view)
}

func loadViewFromNib() -> UIView{

    let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: self.dynamicType)
    let nib = UINib(nibName: "YSCustomCallOutView", bundle: bundle)
    let view = nib.instantiateWithOwner(self, options: nil)[0] as UIView
    return view
}
```

}

It is required method, where i have called it.

```
var calloutView:YSCustomCallOutView!
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didSelectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!){


    if(!view.annotation .isKindOfClass(MKUserLocation)){

    }
    calloutView =  YSCustomCallOutView(frame: CGRectMake(-42,-91,173,91))
    calloutView.ysSeeListingDetail_Button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("checkin:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)
    calloutView.ysSeeDirections_Button.addTarget(self, action: Selector("checkout:"), forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.TouchUpInside)

    view.addSubview(calloutView)

}

func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, didDeselectAnnotationView view: MKAnnotationView!) {

        calloutView.removeFromSuperview()
}

func checkin(sender:UIButton){

    println("Hello")
}

func checkout(sender:UIButton){

    println("Friend")
}
```

Comment: I guess you are adding callout view again and again. this line seems culprit
view.addSubview(calloutView)... Only create view first time when it is nil.

Comment: When i am click on the flag then show the callout view after that click on button then button code not fire.

Comment: did you tried what I said ? have you tried debugging ?

Comment: I am not understand what you say..

Comment: I have tried your suggestion but it is not working.

Comment: you don't know how to debug app ? ok just search on google debug ios app xcode and you will get some articles so try reading them.

Comment: i know that. How to debug xcode app.

Comment: email your source code to this email address rahul.vyas.09@gmail.com

Comment: Please see this link [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28461487/how-to-handle-taps-on-a-custom-callout-view/47607357#47607357).